# callback function for mosquitto c APIs is not getting called

Tags: c++, c, mqtt, mosquitto

For some reason, I had to use C APIs in C++ code. Would anyone please help me in finding the reason for which this code is not working.

```
void ConfigureBroker()
{
   auto res = mosquitto_lib_init();
   if (res == MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
      std::cout<<" mosquitto_lib_init succeed. "<<std::endl;
   else
      std::cout<<" mosquitto_lib_init failed with result : "<<res<<std::endl;

   struct mosquitto * mosq = NULL;
   const char *clientId = "mydev";
   mosq = mosquitto_new(clientId, true, NULL);
   if (!mosq) {
      std::cout<<" mosquitto_new failed. "<<std::endl;
      return;
   }
   else
      std::cout<<" mosquitto_new succeed. "<<std::endl;

   res = mosquitto_tls_set(mosq, "path/to/CA.crt", NULL,
                         "path/to/crts/DeviceCert1.crt",
                         "path/to/DeviceCert1.key", NULL);

   if (MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS == res)
      std::cout<<"mosquitto_tls_set succeed."<<std::endl;
   else
      std::cout<<"mosquitto_tls_set failed with result : "<<res<<std::endl;

   mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, my_connect_callback);

   const char *host = "amazonaws.com";
   res = mosquitto_connect(mosq, host, 8883, 60);

   if (MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS == res)
      std::cout<<"mosquitto_connect succeed."<<std::endl;
   else
      std::cout<<"mosquitto_connect failed with result : "<<res<<std::endl;

   while(!mosquitto_loop(mosq, -1, 1))
      std::cout<<"mosquitto_loop_forever suceed. \n "<<std::endl;
}
```

The output to the above code is as below

```
mosquitto_lib_init succeed.
mosquitto_new succeed.
mosquitto_tls_set succeed.
mosquitto_connect succeed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
mosquitto_loop_forever suceed.
```

> 1. my_connect_callback() function does get called even though mosquitto_connect() returns 0. In fact none of the callback functions
>      get call.
> 2. Though the APIs execute successfully, fail to push data into AWS.

mosquitto_publish() has been removed from the above code deliberately which results success as well. Any help will be appreciated.

> FYI : mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq, -1, 1); **fails** with error **A TLS error occured.**
>
> Now tested with **mosquitto_pub** with the same certificates and the result show there would be problem with certificates which i may need to check

```
Client mosqpub|11358-PCMA4GF11 sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

Comment: You can check the AWS console and cloudwatch to see if the connection was successful. As for `fail to push data` the code snippet doesn't publish any message - what are you expecting to appear?

Comment: You probably also want to set the `host` to your iot endpoint instead of `amazonaws.com`

Comment: @blt I have deliberately removed the lines of code for publish to keep the lines of code less. callback functions (e.g. my_connect_callback)  do not get call even though the mosquitto_connect is successful is my biggest concern.

Comment: For ease of read i have added just "amazonaws.com" else i have a pretty good 39 byte size long string as iot endpoint. Thanks for your response @blt

Comment: Which CA certificate are you using? The AWS IoT Cloudwatch logs may also help.

Comment: @blt After giving the right ca.crt, all the callbacks started to get called (my_connect_callback and my_publish_callback). If my_publish_callback gets called then the publish is success that's what my understanding is. But i do not see data in AWS, would you like to help me in figuring out what would be the cause of this ?

Comment: I suggest you edit this question or create a new one with what you have tried. Otherwise, I recommend checking the Cloudwatch logs.